# how to filter the data set contains the values?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I am working on asp.net application and am new to it. Here I have some id like selected=1,2,3 I just want  to know that if this id's dataset contains or not? I don't have any idea how to check this.

Here my code
             selected=1,2,3

```
         GVSubSelectDtls.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
         DataRow[] foundRows = ds.Tables[0].Select(selected.ToString());

         GVSubSelectDtls.DataBind();
```

but I am getting an error. How can I resolve this?

Comment: What error you are getting?

Comment: your question is unclear..Is `id` a column in your dataset table..Is `selected` an array!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use Column Names inside `Select` like:

```
DataRow[] foundRows = ds.Tables[0].Select("MyColumnName = 'My Column value'");
```

In your case:

```
GVSubSelectDtls.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
DataRow[] foundRows = ds.Tables[0].Select("ID IN ('1','2','3')");
GVSubSelectDtls.DataBind();
```

Comment: Thanks for reply Usman Khan but i am getting some error    DataRow[] foundRows = ds.Tables[0].Select("SubjectId IN ('" +SubIds + "')");
            "Cannot perform '=' operation on System.Int32 and System.String."  please check this

Comment: thanks i made some mistake it's working thanks mr Usman Khalid